# generate a query from data over columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Any idea on how to make a clean code that from a dataframe like

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(['Ricardo','Andres','Andres'],[1,2,2])),columns=['name','id'])
df
Out[5]: 
      name  id
0  Ricardo   1
1   Andres   2
2   Andres   2
```

make a query like

```
((name == 'Ricardo') | (name == 'Andres') ) & ( (id == 1) | (id ==2) )
```

it's like all columns unique values joined by | operator and those joined by and & operator... I have made it using iteration over data, but the code is pretty ugly

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: a string to query for the data unique in the columns: ((name == 'Ricardo') | (name == 'Andres') ) & ( (id == 1) | (id ==2) )

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, using your definition of the data frame `df`.

```
mask = df['name'].isin({'Andres', 'Ricardo'}) & df['id'].isin({1, 2})
df[mask]

      name  id
0  Ricardo   1
1   Andres   2
2   Andres   2
```

Comment: a very similar ordering can  made by stacking df.stack(), but how to make a next step clean for the string construction...

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleaner I can get...

```
query = []
for field, values in df.stack().reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=['level_1',0]).groupby('level_1'):
    query.append( '('+('('+str(field)+' == '+values[0].astype(str)+')').str.cat(sep = ' | ')+' )' )

' & '.join (query)

Out[29]: '((id == 1) | (id == 2) ) & ((name == Ricardo) | (name == Andres) )'
```